# lisp - should be a lambda expression

Tags: lisp, clisp

I'm trying to return (values str ((+ x 3) y)) from the function it resides in.

code snippet:

```
(if (<my condition>)
    (values str ((+ x 3) y))
    (values str ((+ x 2) y)))
```

gives error:

```
(+ X 3) SHOULD BE A LAMBDA EXPRESSION
```

but `(values str (y (+ x 3)))` works fine.

why?

Comment: Can you add a little more context? What are the values of x and y here? It looks like y is acting like a function.

Comment: Can you explain what `((+ x 3) y)` does or should do?

Comment: perhaps `(y (+ x 3))` should be literal `'(y (+ x 3))` or perhaps missing an operator `(* y (+ x 3))`? Perhaps you have define the function `y`?

Answer (score 6):

The S-expression `((+ x 3) y)` cannot be evaluated because the first list element is not funcallable (it should name a function or be a lambda expression).

So, to avoid evaluation, you need to quote it:

```
(if (<my condition>)
    (values str '((+ x 3) y))
    (values str '((+ x 2) y)))
```

Then you will return a list of length 2 (containing a list of length 3 and a symbol `y`) as your second value. If, however, you want to return the *values* of `(+ x 2)` and `y` in the list, you will want to do something like

```
(values str (list (+ x (if <condition> 3 2)) y))
```

or maybe return 3 values instead of 2:

```
(values str
        (+ x (if <condition> 3 2))
        y)
```

On the other hand, `y` is a symbol, which, apparently, names a function in your image, so `(y (+ x 3))` evaluates fine (it calls function `y` on the result of adding `3` to `x`).